# Twitter4j : Search

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I use Twitter4j to get status with hashtag :

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
              .setOAuthConsumerKey("*******")
              .setOAuthConsumerSecret("****")
              .setOAuthAccessToken("*****")
              .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*****");
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
            Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j yusukey");
            QueryResult result;
            try {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
                    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
                }
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I replaced the *** with keys , 
But the application is unable to start

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app_evnt/com.example.app_evnt.SocialNetwork}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all networkcalls are not allowed on main thread, you can try it like this to do it in another thread:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
              .setOAuthConsumerKey("*******")
              .setOAuthConsumerSecret("****")
              .setOAuthAccessToken("*****")
              .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*****");
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            final Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
            Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j yusukey");

            new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
                        for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
                                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
                        }
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: Now the application start , but nothing is printed

Comment: could it be that no results are found? Try printing something outside the for loop